# Keep unique variable in for loop widget command

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, optionmenu

Im adding/removing strings from an optionmenu widget and i've learned that you have to run a command or function when a string is added that sets the widget variable to that string. This is done automatically for strings provided when the widget is originally created.

```
from tkinter import *

def _print(var, string):
    print(string)
    var.set(string)

lst = ['hello', 'bob', 'testing']

main = Tk()
var = StringVar()
options = OptionMenu(main, var, 'option1')
options.grid()

for string in lst:
    options['menu'].add_command(label=string, command=lambda: _print(var, string))

main.mainloop()
```

As you click each option in the menu it should print the string on the widget so you know you have it selected. The problem is that the for loop is setting all of the commands to use the same variable. It looks like its just not keeping a unique variable for each line that is run. I've tried `lambda event, i=string: _print(var, i)` but even if I set the _print function to receive an event lambda always says its missing an event. Maybe i'm trying to do the i=string part wrong or it cant be done this way.

How can I keep the variable "string" unique for each add_command line that is run?

Comment: You were pretty close, you need `lambda event, i=string: _print(var, i)`. See [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

Comment: @eugenhu sorry that was actually a typo in my question. I am using "i" when I call _print(). See updated question. Still get error that lambda missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'.

Comment: Oh right, yeah it would be because `event` is an unnecessary parameter, using `lambda i=string: _print(var, i)` works.

Comment: That was it. I tried lambda, i=string: but not without the comma. Please submit as answer so you can have credit.